# how to append something to javascript variable

Tags: javascript

i have a `<select>` tag

i want redirect user onchange

i got an code and it works fine

the code is

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="&s=1">1</option>
<option value="&s=2">2</option>
<option value="&s=3">3</option>
<option value="&s=4">4</option>
</select>
```

The problem here is :

The current link is: `http://anlink.com/page.php?categ=4&subc=2`

when i change option

i got redirected to `http://anlink.com/&s=1`

but i want it redirect to

```
http://anlink.com/page.php?categ=4&subc=2&s=1
```

So, i want edit the javascript code to something like this

```
if (this.value) window.location.href=
http://anlink.com/page.php?categ=4&subc=2 + this.value
```

i did not try this code but i think it will fail

Comment: Why not just change the option value from `value="&s=3"` to `value="categ=4&subc=2&s=3"`

Comment: @j08691 because i have a hundreds of options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLocation(field) {
    loc = String(window.location);
    newLoc = loc.replace(/\&s=\d$/gi, "") + field.value;
    window.location = newLoc;
}   
</script>
<select onchange="changeLocation(this)">
<option value="&s=1">1</option>
<option value="&s=2">2</option>
<option value="&s=3">3</option>
<option value="&s=4">4</option>
</select>
```

It replaces any instance of `&s=` with a digit after it with nothing. Then it adds the new value. The reason for this is in case a `&s=` doesn't already exist.

If you would like the "s" value to change based on the "s" in the URL (i.e. when you load the page you have `&s=3` in the URL, you want the select to be on "3" as well), make the following changes:

add `onload="adjustS()"` to the body

add an id to the select (I used "s")

add the following function:

```
function adjustS() {
    sLoc = String(String(window.location).match(/\&s=\d$/gi)).replace(/\&s=/gi, "");
    document.getElementById("s").selectedIndex = Number(sLoc)-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
window.location.href += this.value
```

**Edit:**

```
var href = window.location.href;
var re = /&s\=\d$/;
if (re.test(href)) {
  window.location.href = href.replace(re, this.value);
} else {
  window.location.href += this.value;
}
```

Comment: it became http://anlink.com/page.php?categ=4&subc=2&s=1&s=2&s=3, and still plusing

Comment: This is a simple example, but you can check if the value is present first. Check edit.

Comment: why i don't just use something like this ((( if (this.value) window.location.href=
http://mylink.com/ + this.value ))) Since the link does not change

Comment: i tried the code that i posted above, but i don't know why it does not work